# password_verify not matching passwords

Tags: php, password-encryption

I created a php login web application following a tutorial on the net.
I followed this tutorial: 
http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL

Except from the login function, I fetched all the other code form github here:
https://github.com/peredurabefrog/phpSecureLogin

When I have done everything exactly as described, the logging does not work
I tried to find the point of failure by adding a lot of echo statementsto see where it fails and found it in login function at the call of password_verify():

```
function login($email, $password, $mysqli) {
// Using prepared statements means that SQL injection is not possible.
echo "<p>START USER CHECK</p>";

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, username, password 
    FROM members
   WHERE email = ?
    LIMIT 1")) {
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);  // Bind "$email" to parameter.
    $stmt->execute();    // Execute the prepared query.
    $stmt->store_result();

    // get variables from result.
    $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $username, $db_password);
    $stmt->fetch();

    if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
        // If the user exists we check if the account is locked
        // from too many login attempts 
        echo "<p>USER IN DB WITH EMAIL: $stmt->num_rows</p>";
        echo "<p>PW, UN, DBPW: $user_id, $username, $db_password</p>";
        if (checkbrute($user_id, $mysqli) == true) {
            // Account is locked 
            // Send an email to user saying their account is locked
            echo "<p>WE ARE BRUTING</p>";

            return false;
        } else {
            echo "<p>AT LEAST WE ARE NOT BRUTING</p>";

            // Check if the password in the database matches
            // the password the user submitted. We are using
            // the password_verify function to avoid timing attacks.
            if (password_verify($password, $db_password)) {

                echo "<p>PW VERIFIED</p>";

                // Password is correct!
                // Get the user-agent string of the user.
                $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
                // XSS protection as we might print this value
                $user_id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "", $user_id);
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
                // XSS protection as we might print this value
                $username = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+/", "", $username);
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                $_SESSION['login_string'] = hash('sha512', $db_password . $user_browser);
                // Login successful.
                return true;
            } else {

                echo "<p>PW NOT VERIFIED</p>";
                echo "<p>Password from form (hashed with sha512?): $password</br>Password from DB: $db_password</p>";

                // Password is not correct
                // We record this attempt in the database
                $now = time();
                //$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO login_attempts(user_id, time) VALUES ('$user_id', '$now')");
                return false;
            }
        }
    } else {
        // No user exists.
        return false;
    }
}
```

Result:

> Processing login
>
> USER CHECK
>
> USER IN DB WITH EMAIL: 1
>
> PW, UN, DBPW: 1, sec_user,
>   $2y$10$IrzYJi10j3Jy/K6jzSLQtOLif1wEZqTRQoK3DcS3jdnFEhL4fWM4G
>
> AT LEAST WE ARE NOT BRUTING
>
> PW NOT VERIFIED
>
> Password from form (hashed with sha512?):
>   445fc3655cede6a6c841d08f0776fac92a0118d1d1597046e09909310b2664538642292515aee4737c39826d70508466f5df36417f09274cb470ca4b6857be7a
>   Password from DB:
>   $2y$10$IrzYJi10j3Jy/K6jzSLQtOLif1wEZqTRQoK3DcS3jdnFEhL4fWM4G

I can not see the problem, is the hashed password incorrect?

I have put some output in the forms.js script, ands printed the none-hashed and hashed pw.

```
function formhash(form, password) {
// Create a new element input, this will be our hashed password field.
var p = document.createElement("input");

// Add the new element to our form.
form.appendChild(p);
p.name = "p";
p.type = "hidden";
p.value = hex_sha512(password.value);

alert("PW: "+password.value+" -- Hashed: "+p.value);

// Make sure the plaintext password doesn't get sent.
password.value = "";

// Finally submit the form.
form.submit();
```

}

> PW: 6ZaxN2Vzm9NUJT2y -- Hashed: 445fc3655cede6a6c841d08f0776fac92a0118d1d1597046e09909310b2664538642292515aee4737c39826d70508466f5df36417f09274cb470ca4b6857be7a

I have checked other simular question, but their solutions failed or did not apply to my problem.

Sorry, I am lost.

Comment: Have you encrypted the password coming from login to check `if (password_verify($password, $db_password)) {`. Because, encrypted password is stored in DB.

Comment: Why have you hashed `$password`? It should be the plaintext password that the user has entered on the login page.... if you need to transfer the password securely between the browser and the webserver, you use https, not hashing the password in the browser

Comment: @NanaPartykar; I have used the exact code from github. So if the file needed to be encrypted before the password_verify, then the code provided and the tutorial is incorrect or incomplete, so, should I use password_hash?

Comment: @MarkBaker; the tutorial explained that forms should hashed, so I followed the advise. I could use https.

Comment: You should use https; I don't know what tutorial suggested hashing in js, because it will always cause you validation problems on the server; but https is the best solution

Comment: Already installed mod_ssl, will remove the form hashing, etc. Will post results.

Comment: After removing the formhash function everything worked fine.
Going to use SSL, thank you all for your pointers.